# Netty Snoop-like implementation does not receive server response data

Tags: http, netty, snoop

I've implemented a Netty Snoop-like HTTP server and client.

The server can be tested easily with a browser - it works as expected. The client is harder to test but through debugging I can tell that it receives the headers just fine but it doesn't seem to receive the HTTP response body.

Since I know the server is sending the body (by checking in the browser) I'm wondering why the client code can't see it, or maybe can't decode it.

I am using Netty 4.0.15 as it appears to be the most stable release right now. You can see my version of the ClientHandler and ClientInitalizer classes at http://pastebin.com/tQ6d72pn And you can see my ServerHandler and ServerInitalizer classes at http://pastebin.com/JbHrTEkg

No doubt I'm doing something stupid, any help would be really great!

Comment: The pastes were removed, so I can't give you a meaningful answer.  You might consider filing an issue to our issue tracker with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Trustin, I eventually worked through the problems I was having. The core of the problem seems to be lack of docs and debugging mechanisms, but then isn't that almost always the case? Thanks again.